# O CSS está todo desestruturado e os elementos fora do lugar

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, angular

eu estou aqui tentando fazer um site pro curso, moldando o css dele como deveria ser feito, só que tem um problema. Fiz todo o modelo do curso, só que o css saiu de lugar totalmente, ficou todo destruturado, as coisas fora de lugar e eu não sei o que fazer pra resolver, não é a primeira vez que tento fazer um html e css na minha maquina e gera essa bagunça, alguém sabe se tem alguma configuração que podemos fazer para resolver? Tentei modificar o html, o java script e tudo mas realmente não resolve, o que fazer?[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bhNF.jpg)

Como por exemplo o “A vista no pix” deveria ta dentro desse card, esse texto fora do lugar, não foi assim que foi montado e o pior que cada modificação prejudica a estrutura do site todo

Comment: Importante seguir as orientações já dadas em sua [pergunta original](/q/592700/70)